# spring boot multithreating

Tags: многопоточность, spring

У меня в приложении есть класс.

```
public Robot implements Callable<String> {
@Override
    public String call() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            while (true) {
                /// doing somthing
                monitor.wait(15000L)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Затем есть сервисный класс, который запускает объекты Robot

```
List<Robot> robots = <10000 роботов>
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(robots.size());
threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(robots.size());
threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();

for (Robot robot : robots) {
    try {
         Future<String> result = threadPoolTaskExecutor.submit(robot);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         log.warn("", e);
    }
}
```

если я в таком виде запускаю, то получаю

```
[70,174s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
```

Смысл, чтоб каждый робот каждые 15сек выполнял действие и засыпал.

Само действие занимает доли секунды.

Есть мысль взять пул потоков и в цикле, раз в 15 сек прогонять через него список роботов. Но у меня есть условие, чтоб первое действие робот выполнял со случайной задержкой, а все остальные повторяющиеся действия с интервалом ~15сек после предыдущего.
И вот как это реализовать, придумать не могу...

Comment: Используйте `@Scheduled`

Comment: Но тогда нить, которая начнет выполнять задачу в роботе, будет зависать на время @Sheduled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запуска 10000 потоков, с размером стэка 1mb, требуется 10gb памяти - и это они ещё делать ничего не начали.

У Явовского пула потоков есть метод для создания повторяющейся задачи, причём отдельно задается стартовая задержка (в твоём случае - случайная) и интервал повторения (15 сек)

```
class Robot {

    ....

    private volatile ScheduledFuture task;
    private volatile boolean stopped;

    public void setTask(final ScheduledFuture task) {
        this.task = task;
        if (stopped) {
            this.task.cancel(false);
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        this.stopped = true;
        if (this.task != null) {
            this.task.cancel(false);
        }
    }   
}

var pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
var rnd = new Random();
for (int r=0; r < 10_000; r++) {
  var robot = ...;
  var startDelay = rnd.nextInt(15); // стартовая задержка 0..14 секунд
  var task = pool.scheduleAtFixedRate(robot, startDelay, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  robot.setTask(task);
}
```

Естественно, в теле робота не должно быть никаких `sleep`, `wait` и т.д.

Comment: Александр, спасибо за ответ.
Можете еще помочь разобраться с отменой задания в scheduledpool. Как робот может выкинуть сам себя из этого пула? Я не могу понять механизм действия pool.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);

Comment: Добавил в код. Обрати внимание, что `setTask() ` и `stop()` теоритически могут быть вызваны в разном порядке, если `startDelay=0`, задача быстро отработала и решила себя остановить